# c++ opengl draw texture in front of another texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw `texture2` *partly* (the textures have different position-coordinates) on top of `texture1`. The textures is supposed have different images.

The code below works fine except that `texture1` gets in front of `texture2`, but it should be the other way around.

If I change the drawing order, `texture2` get in front of `texture1` as desired but `texture2` gets the same image as `texture1`.
What am I doing wrong here?

In my init function:

```
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "color");
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 2, "texCoordIn");
glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "fragmentColor");
linkShaderProgram(shaderProgram);

texture = ilutGLLoadImage("image1.jpg"); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);          
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); 

texture2 = ilutGLLoadImage("image2.png");
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);        
int texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "colortexture");     
glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);
```

My vertex-shader:

```
in vec3     position;
in vec3     color;
out vec3    outColor;

in vec2     texCoordIn; 
out vec2    texCoord; 

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; 

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1);
    outColor = color; 
    texCoord = texCoordIn; 
}
```

My fragment-shader:

```
in vec3 outColor;
uniform sampler2D colortexture;
in vec2 texCoord;    

out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main() 
{
    fragmentColor = texture2D(colortexture, texCoord.xy); 
}
```

In my draw-function: (If I draw in the order below, the textures get their desired images. But if I change the order, both textures get image1)

```
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);             
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); 
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Your described behaviour does not make much sense on the first look, but I can't test it myself right now. Anyway in the given code you only set `glUniform1i(texLoc, 0);` so the your shader will always read the texture from _slot_ `0`, but you activate your texture2 for `GL_TEXTURE1` (slot `1`) so either you need to change your uniform before each `glDrawElements` to `0` and `1` according to the texture you want to draw, or you would need to use the same slot to bind the texture before rendering  e.g. `GL_TEXTURE0`.

Comment: Aah so I only need GL_TEXTURE0 to draw TWO textures? Thanks it worked.

Comment: For a `glDrawElement` you need as many slots as you define with `uniform sampler2D` in your shader you use to draw, because you only have one `sampler2D` you only need one slot. How you would organise your application depends on the use-case. If you bring your GPU to its limit you would try to avoid as many OpenGL API calls as possible and you would try to avoid as many changes on the GPU as possible. But for example this is not really relevant.